# GEOSPARQL "within" and stardog

Tags: sparql, stardog, geosparql

I'm struggling with the geosparql in particular geo:Within.

The documentation I can find at: [open gis documentation](http://www.opengis.net/doc/IS/geosparql/1.0) states that it needs a `geo:SpatialObject` and that a `geo:Feature` is a type of `geo:SpatialObject`. I have a number of features which have points for their location. When I run

```
SELECT Distinct * WHERE {   
  ?g geo:asWKT ?gWKT .  
}
```

I get 25 points returned, all of which should be in the (rather large) polygon defined below.

However

```
SELECT * WHERE {   
  ?g geo:asWKT ?gWKT .
  FILTER geof:within( ?g ,"POLYGON(51.45, -0.115,51.52,-0.08)"^^geo:wktLiteral  ) .
}
```

Causes "Internal server error".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to GeoSPARQL, though fairly familiar with standard SPARQL.

Comment: Did you enable the support for polygons? As mentioned here: http://docs.stardog.com/#_enhanced_polygons

Comment: I did indeed.
I've also fixed the error with my definition of the polygon, it's now
`SELECT Distinct ?g WHERE {   
  ?g geo:asWKT ?gWKT .
  FILTER (geof:within( ?g ,"POLYGON((-0.05 51.1 , 0.25 51.1 ,-0.05 52,0.25 52 ))"^^geo:wktLiteral  ))   
}
`

Comment: Further to the above: I believed I'd enabled the support for polygons, but I'd done it wrong.
For the benefit of others: the jts-core jar file needs to be located in a folder called `ext`, which you need to create under server in the stardog install dir

Answer (score 3):

Your shape is still defined incorrectly. It seems like you are trying to create a simple rectangle, so as a POLYGON it would be `"POLYGON(( -0.05 51.1, 0.25 51.1, 0.25 52, -0.05 52, -0.05 51.1 ))"^^geo:wktLiteral` (Corner 1, Corner 2, Corner 3, Corner 4, Corner 1 to close it off).

Alternatively, you can simplify this (and remove the need for JTS) by using an ENVELOPE like so: `"ENVELOPE(-0.05, 0.25, 52, 51.1)"^^geo:wktLiteral` (minLat, maxLat, ***maxLon***, minLon - Notice the odd order required).

Comment: You understand correctly, ENVELOPE is the solution I required, many thanks.